# Unable to get a dropdown value using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formik-material-ui

I'm new to reactjs. I have created a dropdown for a company list and want to get values. I still couldn't be able to get values from the dropdown. I've tried several methods of retrieving data but not able to do that. can anyone help me to get values? Here is some of my code.

```
<Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
        <SoftBox mb={1} ml={0.5} lineHeight={0} display="inline-block">
          <SoftTypography
            component="label"
            variant="caption"
            fontWeight="bold"
            textTransform="capitalize">
            Country
          </SoftTypography>
        </SoftBox>
        <Select input={<SoftInput />} value={country} onChange={handleSetCountry}>
          <MenuItem value="...">country</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="10">Hello 10</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="11">Hello 11</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="12">Hello 12</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </Grid>
```

Here is my whole code.

```js
    /**
    =========================================================
    * Soft UI Dashboard PRO React - v4.0.0
    =========================================================

    * Product Page: https://material-ui.com/store/items/soft-ui-pro-dashboard/
    * Copyright 2022 Creative Tim (https://www.creative-tim.com)

    Coded by www.creative-tim.com
     =========================================================
    * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
    */

    import { useState } from "react";
    // prop-type is a library for typechecking of props
    import PropTypes from "prop-types";
    // @mui material components
    import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
    import Select from "@mui/material/Select";
    import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
    // Soft UI Dashboard PRO React components
    import Switch from "@mui/material/Switch";
    import SoftBox from "components/SoftBox";
    import SoftTypography from "components/SoftTypography";
    import SoftInput from "components/SoftInput";
    // NewUser page components
    import FormField from "layouts/pages/new/new-company/components/FormField";
    import { DateTimePicker } from "@material-ui/pickers";
    import { distance } from "chroma-js";
    function General({ formData }) {
      const [country, setCountry] = useState("...");
      const handleSetCountry = (event) => setCountry(event.target.value);
      const { formField, values, errors, touched } = formData;
      const { comNumber, address1, address2, city, state, postcode, additional, phone, phone1, fax, web } = formField;
      const { comNumber: comNumberV, address1: address1V, address2: address2V, city: cityV, state: stateV, postcode: postcodeV, additional: additionalV, 
        phone: phoneV, phone1: phone1V, fax: faxV, web: webV} = values;
      const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date());
      const [rememberMe, setRememberMe] = useState(false);

      const handleSetRememberMe = () => setRememberMe(!rememberMe);


      return (
        <SoftBox>
          <SoftTypography variant="h5" fontWeight="bold">
            General 
          </SoftTypography>
          <SoftBox mt={1.625}>
            <Grid container spacing={3}>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <FormField
                  type={comNumber.type}
                  label={comNumber.label}
                  name={comNumber.name}
                  value={comNumberV}
                  placeholder={comNumber.placeholder}
                  error={errors.comNumber && touched.comNumber}
                  success={comNumberV.length > 0 && !errors.comNumber}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                
                  <FormField
                    type={address1.type}
                    label={address1.label}
                    name={address1.name}
                    value={address1V}
                    placeholder={address1.placeholder}
                  />
             
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid container spacing={3}>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <FormField
                    type={address2.type}
                    label={address2.label}
                    name={address2.name}
                    value={address2V}
                    placeholder={address2.placeholder}
                  /></Grid>
                     <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
               <FormField
                    type={city.type}
                    label={city.label}
                    name={city.name}
                    value={cityV}
                    placeholder={city.placeholder}
                  />
                {/* <FormField
                  type={city.type}
                  label={city.label}
                  name={city.name}
                  value={cityV}
                  placeholder={city.placeholder}
                  error={errors.city && touched.city}
                  success={cityV.length > 0 && !errors.city}
                /> */}
              </Grid>
              </Grid>
              {/* <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
                <SoftBox mb={1} ml={0.5} lineHeight={0} display="inline-block">
                  <SoftTypography
                    component="label"
                    variant="caption"
                    fontWeight="bold"
                    textTransform="capitalize"
                  >
                    State
                  </SoftTypography>
                </SoftBox>
                <Select input={<SoftInput />} value={state} onChange={handleSetState}>
                  <MenuItem value="...">state</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="10">Hello 10</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="11">Hello 11</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="12">Hello 12</MenuItem>
                </Select>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
                <FormField
                  type={zip.type}
                  label={zip.label}
                  name={zip.name}
                  value={zipV}
                  placeholder={zip.placeholder}
                  error={errors.zip && touched.zip}
                  success={zipV.length > 0 && !errors.zip}
                />
              </Grid>
            </Grid> */}
             <Grid container spacing={3}>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
               <FormField
                    type={state.type}
                    label={state.label}
                    name={state.name}
                    value={stateV}
                    placeholder={state.placeholder}
                  />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
               <FormField
                    type={postcode.type}
                    label={postcode.label}
                    name={postcode.name}
                    value={postcodeV}
                    placeholder={postcode.placeholder}
                    error={errors.postcode && touched.postcode}
                  success={postcodeV.length > 0 && !errors.postcode}
                  />
                </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <Grid container spacing={3}>
                <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <SoftBox mb={1} ml={0.5} lineHeight={0} display="inline-block">
                  <SoftTypography
                    component="label"
                    variant="caption"
                    fontWeight="bold"
                    textTransform="capitalize">
                    Country
                  </SoftTypography>
                </SoftBox>
                <Select input={<SoftInput />} value={country} onChange={handleSetCountry}>
                  <MenuItem value="...">country</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="10">Hello 10</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="11">Hello 11</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="12">Hello 12</MenuItem>
                </Select>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
               <FormField
                    type={additional.type}
                    label={additional.label}
                    name={additional.name}
                    value={additionalV}
                    placeholder={additional.placeholder}
                  />
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
              <Grid container spacing={3}>
                <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <FormField
                    type={phone.type}
                    label={phone.label}
                    name={phone.name}
                    value={phoneV}
                    placeholder={phone.placeholder}
                    error={errors.phone && touched.phone}
                  success={phoneV.length > 0 && !errors.phone}
                  />
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <FormField
                    type={phone1.type}
                    label={phone1.label}
                    name={phone1.name}
                    value={phone1V}
                    placeholder={phone1.placeholder}
                    error={errors.phone1 && touched.phone1}
                  success={phone1V.length > 0 && !errors.phone1}
                  />
                  </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid container spacing={3}>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
               <FormField
                    type={fax.type}
                    label={fax.label}
                    name={fax.name}
                    value={faxV}
                    placeholder={fax.placeholder}
                  />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
               <FormField
                    type={web.type}
                    label={web.label}
                    name={web.name}
                    value={webV}
                    placeholder={web.placeholder}
                  />
                </Grid>
                </Grid>
                {/* <Grid container spacing={3}>
                <Grid item xs={12} >
                <FormField
                    type={distance.type}
                    label={distance.label}
                    name={distance.name}
                    value={distanceV}
                    placeholder={distance.placeholder}
                  />
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <SoftBox display="flex" alignItems="center">
                  <Switch checked={rememberMe} onChange={handleSetRememberMe} />
                  <SoftTypography
                    variant="button"
                    fontWeight="regular"
                    onClick={handleSetRememberMe}
                    sx={{ cursor: "pointer", userSelect: "none" }}
                  >
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;Company Opted Out From Surveys
                  </SoftTypography>
                </SoftBox> */}
          </SoftBox>
        </SoftBox>
      );
    }

    // typechecking props for Address
    General.propTypes = {
      formData: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.object, PropTypes.func]).isRequired,
    };

    export default General;
```

I need to get dropdown values. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should really create a small example in Codesandbox and post it here...

Anyway,

As far as I can see you have two different dropdowns/select components (state and country).

You get no value from neither of them ? The Country one seems to be okay, but the State is missing its event handler (?).
What does a simple console.log output show?:

```
const handleSetCountry = (event) => {
 console.log(event.target.value);
 setCountry(event.target.value);
}
```

Also, try without the

```
input={<SoftInput />}
```

and see what happens